# Adding item to CoreData stops showing on next app load

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a strange bug where I can add an item to an array in CoreData, which shows fine on the view. But upon next app load, it breaks all my CoreData models?

To replicate: I have two models, one called "Person", which contains a Transformable array of "Device".

```
extension Person {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Person> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var devices: [Device]?
}
```

```
extension Device {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Device> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Device>(entityName: "Device")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
}
```

Here is my view code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(entity: Person.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    var persons: FetchedResults<Person>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(persons) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.name!)")

                    ForEach(item.devices!) { device in
                        Text("device")
                    }
                }                
            }
            Button(action: addItem) {
                Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Person(context: viewContext)
            newItem.name = "Test test"
            newItem.age = Int64.random(in: 0..<100)
            newItem.gender = "Male"
            newItem.devices = [Device].init()
            
            let newDevice = Device(context: viewContext)
            newDevice.name = "iPhone"
            newItem.devices?.append(newDevice)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When adding a Person, it also adds the device successfully. However, when I then restart the app, it stops showing any data.. and when I add more items it doesn't show anymore. I have to delete the sqlite db, or delete the app from the simulator.

Is there something wrong with binding to the models on startup? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be how you are instantiating `devices` and how you have the array set up.

instead of using `newItem.devices = [Device].init()`

use new `newItem.addToDevices(newDevice)` (the addTo...() might be worded a little different).

For this to work you have to have a "To many" relationship with `Device` vs Transformable

The [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html) can offer more information

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this now.

Comment: This worked. I've had to modify my code to handle NSSet but this seems to be the way to handle arrays of data in Core Data. Thanks!